# disable keydown for div

Tags: jquery, keydown, keycode

How do I disable keydown for a specific div? The options i've tried have all made it so that none of my divs accept any keys anymore. The keys I want to disable for my div are 1 and 2.

here is where I list what each key does:

```
    $(document).keydown( function(e)
            {
                var press= "";
                if ( boolKeyDepressed )
                    return;
                else
                    boolKeyDepressed = true;

        var e = e || window.event;
                var ltr = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;

//            alert( "You pressed " + ltr );

                if ( ltr == 13 ) 
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }


                    switch(ltr)
                    {
                        case 49: // "1"
                        case 97: // "1"


                                FunctionHandleRsp("1") 
                               //does something with the value 1




                            break;

                        case 50: // "2"
                        case 98: // "1"



                        FunctionHandleRsp("2") 
                      // does something with the value 2


                    }
                }

//etc etc
```

To disable them for the div with id "myDiv" I added

```
if (screens[current].id=="myDiv"){
                            event.preventDefault();
                            }
```

and

```
$("#myDiv").unbind('keydown');
```

and

```
$("#myDiv).keydown(function(event) { 
             return false;
                    });
```

but none of these methods work. I put them in a function that shows the div on the screen. What these all do is they disable keydown for all my divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `event.stopPropagation()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Happy to hear it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

usually a div can not have a keyboard input focus, so it will never receive keystrokes.

you are getting keystrokes on the document. the div's are not involved here. you might want to check if the mouse is over a specific div, when the key event is received through the document. depending on that you can process the key event.

otherwise you will be able to receive key events directly through the div's if you set its [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.contentEditable) attribute to true.

a div without content editable does not recive keystrokes. check toggling the `contentEditable` property in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7sq5ot2a/)

Comment: Actually, you can: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: so element.contentEditable property would have to be set. than focus must be checked.

Comment: @dreamlab: Not necessarily.  The key event can also bubble up/propagate through a div from an input element.  It can be handled at the div.  This is how event delegation works in jQuery.

Comment: It doesn't have to be editable -- isn't this how hotkeys are done?

Comment: True; I was going to add that as well, but from the OP's question, I'm assuming that the div can have the focus.

Comment: i meant check if the div gets focused. this wouldn't work if it is under something else. great to learn about contentEditable. thanks @CullenJ

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(":not(#somediv, #somdiv *)").keydown(function(e) {
    ...
});
```